# Switching cell color based on current one using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, if-statement

I am trying to change the cell color when a button is clicked. Here's my current code. (I am very new to this and am just messing around with things)

```
function changeColor() {
if(document.getElementById("changeColorId").bgColor = "yellow"){
            document.getElementById("changeColorId").bgColor = "green";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("changeColorId").bgColor = "blue";
        }
    }
```

I am attempting to change the background color of 'changeColorId' to green if the current color is yellow (which it does do). However, I would also like it to change to blue if I click the button again, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: do you wanna do this only in javascript or are you open to using jquery?

Comment: What is the context in-which this function work on it? i.e What is your HTML?

Comment: check out both answer below that point out 2 problems on the code. First is the equal operation which typo with assignment. Second is the correct properties call to backgroundColor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax

> document.getElementById("changeColorId").bgColor

Following is correct syntax to get the color property of the element.

> document.getElementById("changeColorId").style.color

Please check the code, Simple place code in html page it will work.

```
> <button onclick="changeColor();"  >Click me</button>

> <div id="changeColorId" style="background-color:yellow">

> </div>
```

```
    
         function changeColor() {
         var elementStyle = document.getElementById("changeColorId").style;

         if(elementStyle.backgroundColor == "yellow"){
            elementStyle.backgroundColor = "green";
          } 
           else if(elementStyle.backgroundColor == "green"){    
               elementStyle.backgroundColor = "blue";
          }
          else {
            elementStyle.backgroundColor = "yellow";
          }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

For comparisons use the **equality operator** `==`, because `=` is an **attribution**. See [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) for more.

Also, to access the element's css you have to access the `style` attribute, followed by the property in camelcase:

> document.getElementById('*elementId*').style.*property*

I think that what you you want to reach is this:

```
function changeColor() {
  if(document.getElementById("changeColorId").style.backgroundColor === "yellow"){
    document.getElementById("changeColorId").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("changeColorId").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
}
```

Comment: No, `==` is only enough in the `if`